# Querying data in postgresql by applying filter on JSONB When java class has sub class(jsonb)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-12

I have a table Employee with fileds  id, name, age , Address(as Jsonb string stored in Postgres DB)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Employee  implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
int Id;
@Column
String name;
@Column
int age;

@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
@Type(type="jsonb")
Address address;   // this field is JSONB data stored in postgress DB

// setter and getters

}

public class Address implements Serializable {

String flatNo;
String area;
String state;

// setter and getters
}
```

DB table data format:

```
id |   name   | age |                        address  
---+----------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------
20 | Peter    |  16 | {"area": "KKR", "state": "KARNATAKA", "flatNo": "456"}
21 | Nani     |  20 | {"area": "CTM", "state": "TA", "flatNo": "111"}
```

My query here is: I need to filter data based on jsonb field.

Like need employee full row details based on `area="KKR"`, as area is not direct field of employee, I'm unable to filter data. I'm new to Postgres. Can you please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can do this using the `@>` operator:

```
select *
from employee
where address @> '{"area": "KKR"}';
```

Alternatively with the `->>` operator that returns a single value for a key:

```
select *
from employee
where address ->> 'area' = 'KKR';
```